# Image Button with Java Script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, button

Ok, i'm trying to create a script.js to make a image button, but the code dont want to run!
can you show me what is wrong?

HTML:

```
    <div class="baixo-tudo">
        <div class="botao">
            <img src="./images/bto-net-out.png" />
            <span class="src1">http://www.midnightbsd.org/art/logo/MidnightBSDLogo32x32.png</span>
            <span class="src2">http://www.parmaja.com/projects/firebirdlogo/logo-32x32.png</span>
        </div>
        <div class="botao">
            <img src="./images/bto-net-out.png" />
            <span class="src1">./images/bto-visual-out.png</span>
            <span class="src2">./images/bto-visual-over.png</span>
        </div>
        <div class="botao">
            <img src="./images/bto-net-out.png" />
            <span class="src1">./images/bto-sql-out.png</span>
            <span class="src2">./images/bto-sql-over.png</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Script.js:

```
 $('.baixo-tudo').find('.botao').each(function (i) {

    var imge = $('img');
    var t = $('.botao'),
        src1 = t.find('.src1').text(),
        src2 = t.find('.src2').text();

    imge.mouseover(function () {
        t.attr('src', src1);
    }, function () {
        t.attr('src', src2);
    });
});
```

look: http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/

many neurons firing to create this =/

look now, the imagem disapear: http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/4/

Comment: Include jQuery, I also added log statements: http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/1/

Comment: @ISFO There is no server code. Why the question is tagged to ASP.Net?

Comment: because it is on visual web studio to aspx

Comment: See the edit to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put it in a document.ready call. And as Samuel Reid pointed out, a hover function is what you need. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.baixo-tudo').find('.botao').each(function (i) {

        var imge = $('img');
        var t = $('.botao'),
            src1 = t.find('.src1').text(),
            src2 = t.find('.src2').text();

        imge.hover(function () {
            t.attr('src', src1);
        }, function () {
            t.attr('src', src2);
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT, building on your fiddle.

I am guessing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/5/) is what you want?

```
$('.baixo-tudo').find('.botao').each(function (i) {

    var t = $(this),
        imge = t.children("img"),
        src1 = t.children('.src1').text(),
        src2 = t.children('.src2').text();

    imge.mouseover(function () {
        imge.attr('src', src1);
    });

    imge.mouseout(function () {
        imge.attr('src', src2);
    });
});
```

And even [shorter](http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/6/).

```
$('.baixo-tudo').find('.botao').each(function (i) {

    var t = $(this),
        imge = t.children("img"),
        src1 = t.children('.src1').text(),
        src2 = t.children('.src2').text();

    imge.hover(function () {
        imge.attr('src', src1);
    }, function () {
        imge.attr('src', src2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what you need

```
$('.baixo-tudo').find('.botao').each(function (i) {


    var imge = $(this).find('img');
    var src1 = $(this).find('span.src1').text();

    imge.hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src',src1);

    });

});
```

Adjust it to your needs. I have also edited your fiddle. it works as u needed it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NnUe6/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `mouseover` function to `hover` instead.